# Reset Jade variable after being rendered with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, pug

I am trying to figure out how I would reset a session property to 'undefined' after passing its contents to a Jade template via Express/Node.

I have tried the following:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('template', {
        variableName: req.session.PROPERTY
    });
    req.session.PROPERTY = undefined;
});
```

However, it appears nothing else is being run after the res.render() call. How could I reset the property to undefined after using it in a template?

Comment: are you sure nothing is running after render? try putting a console.log

Comment: Alright. So when I add console.log(req.session.PROPERTY) it does say it was set to undefined as intended but in my session store (rethinkdb) the value remains unchanged.

Comment: You probably have to "write" a change to your session store to make it permanent.  But, you'd have to share what you're using for a session store to be able to offer more details.